# Losing name while serializing object

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

While doing some experiment on serialization, I noticed that my object name is lost when the object is retrieved.  Would you please show me what is going on?

```
void nDB::serialize(macro* myMacro) {
    ofstream ar("macro.dat", ios::binary);
    ar.write((char*)myMacro,sizeof(*myMacro));
}

macro* nDB::deserialize() {
    macro* tmp_macro = (macro*)safemalloc(sizeof(macro));
    ifstream ar("macro.dat", ios::binary);
    ar.read((char*)tmp_macro,sizeof(*tmp_macro));
    printf("My macro name is %s\n",tmp_macro->get_name());
    return tmp_macro;
}
```

And this is what my output is

```
My macro name is \uffffs\uffff>
```

Thank you very much,

Comment: How are you storing the object name?

Comment: Hi David, I store the object name as char*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only storing the static memory for your object. Any dynamically allocated memory your object uses (such as `std::string`, `std::vector` or anything allocated with `malloc`, or `new`) will not be saved since they are located on the heap. You have to serialize and deserialize all dynamically allocated memory as well.

Comment: @Binh The [C++ Middleware Writer](http://webEbenezer.net) takes care of these details.

Comment: Hi David, I understand this. However, my object name is statically allocated, as well as one other attribute called block. However, I was able to retrieve block which stored as a bit field but no name. I have no idea what is happening. If you have any idea would you please help. Thank you,

Comment: How can I post the code now?  This is the comment session, do I need to open another thread?

Comment: @BinhVanPham Edit the original question

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is undefined behavior.

You should **not** be using direct memory manipulation (and especially `malloc` and `free`) in C++, unless manipulating C-like structures (and still...).

For serialization and deserialization, you need a proper library (or to code one yourself, but you don't seem to have the necessary expertise yet).

I would recommend using Boost.Serialization.

But before that, I would recommend reading a C++ primer book (check out the [list compiled here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)). You are not using idiomatic C++, you are using C-like idioms. This will bite you.